# OpenVPN routing, making specific client visible to all

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have the following:

1. Home LAN 192.168.1.1 mask 255.255.255.240
2. NAS in said LAN,
   with internal IP of 192.168.1.8
3. ASUS router with OpenVPN client
   that routes traffic from said NAS through OpenVPN server
4. OpenVPN
   server on a remote cloud, running in docker container
   (https://hub.docker.com/r/kylemanna/openvpn/)
5. client-to-client
   already set in a config of OpenVPN server

Now I want that all OpenVPN clients that request 192.168.1.8 be rerouted to my NAS in home LAN. How do I do that? I take it just having client-to-client is not enough, I have to set routes. I tried the following:

```
### Route Configurations Below
route 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.1.8 255.255.255.240
### Push Configurations Below
push "route 192.168.1.8 255.255.255.240"
push block-outside-dns
push dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
push dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4
### Extra Configurations Below
client-to-client
```

It didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this solution but I think that the easy method is that all of your client conect to your vpn server the vpn asing to each client one ip address when you conect to identify you in the vpn.

So if you use a router and conect it directly to the vpn the router has a vpn ip for Wan Port and the lan port has the Nas 192.168.1.8 so if your client join their router to the vpn they will have also a vpn ip address in the wan port so they can  add an static route for 1.0 network using gateway "your-router-vpn-ip" it should works but you must be sure that your client don´t use in their lan 1.0 also because they will have two differents output for the same network one their lan and outher output your Lan via vpn